# ContextErrorException in Symfony 3

Tags: image, symfony, upload

I am trying to upload images in SF3, and I have this error when I upload:

> Missing argument 2 for Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile::__construct().

This is the part of my entity where is the error is located (line 9 here):

```
public function preUpload()
{
    // if there is no file (optional field)
    if (null === $this->image) {
        return;
    }

    // $file = new File($this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->image);
    $file = new File($this->getUploadRootDir() .'/' . $this->image);
    $uploadedfile = new UploadedFile($this->getUploadRootDir() .'/' . $this->image);

    // the name of the file is its id, one should just store also its extension
    // to make clean, we should rename this attribute to "extension" rather than "url" 
    $this->url = $file->guessExtension();

    // and we generate the alt attribute of the <img> tag,
    // the value of the file name on the user's PC
    $this->alt = $uploadedfile->getClientOriginalName();
}
```

Then my controller :

```
public function mediaEditAction(Request $request)
{
    $media = new Media();
    $form = $this->createForm(MediaType::class, $media);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $file = $media->getImage();
        $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();
        $file->move(
            $this->getParameter('images_directory'),
            $fileName
        );
        $media->setImage($fileName);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($media);
        $em->flush();

        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('Notice', 'Photo added with success');

        // redirection
        $url = $this->generateUrl('medecin_parametre');

        // permanent redirection with the status http 301
        return $this->redirect($url, 301);
    } else {
        return $this->render('DoctixMedecinBundle:Medecin:mediaedit.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear.  The constructor for UploadedFile needs at least two arguments.  You are only passing one.

Comment: Yes i understand. 
But what should be the second argument that I can add here ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are doing unnecessary work and making this a little more complicated than it probably needs to be.  Have you followed this [Symfony guide for How to Upload Files](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html)?

In the meantime, it seems like the image name is what is in `$this->image` so you can just pass that as the 2nd constructor argument.

```
$uploadedfile = new UploadedFile($this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->image, $this->image);
```

However, **UploadedFile** should probably only come from the form submission, and in your entity you would want to use **File** instead - like so:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;

$uploadedfile = new File($this->getUploadRootDir() .'/' . $this->image);
```

Comment: Hi Jason Roman, 
the second option you mentioned is what I did at first but it showed me the following error:      Attempted to call an undefined method named "getClientOriginalName" of class "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File".     And when i try the first solution, this error appear :    Type error: Argument 1 passed to Doctix\MedecinBundle\Service\ImageUpload::upload() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile, string given, called in C:\wamp\www\Doctix-v2\src\Doctix\MedecinBundle\EventListener\ImageUploadListener.php on line 45

Comment: Right, you can't use `getOriginalName()` on a regular File because that's not an uploaded file.  I would try looking at the link I posted for Symfony's guide to uploading files.  It appears you're kind of mixing behavior - your `preUpload` Doctrine listener has no intrinsic knowledge about what page you are on or that you uploaded a file.

Comment: yes I understood the error message for getclientoriginalname, and that's why I went through the other option. Thanks. I wait your answer.

Comment: I have nothing further to add to my answer - you'll want to go through the Symfony documentation that I linked to further help you out.